# read parameters from txt in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I need to read parameters from a txt file for my program in Linux. But the result is that some of the parameters read from the txt file have the correct value, but some of them have a wrong value. Somebody has met this problem? I have translated the format of the txt in windows into Linux with the command dos2unix. I need your help, Thanks.

The read function is as follows:

```
template <class T>int ReadFileVar(ifstream *inClientFile, const char var_name[], T *var)
{
//inClientFile - pointer to the previously opened File stream
//var_name - contains the name of the variable
//var - pointer to a long, the function will return the value of the variable in this

int length_var_name = (int) strlen(var_name);
char line[512];
int i, j;

while (inClientFile->getline(line,512))
{
    if (line[0] != '/' && line[1] != '/')
    {
        i = 0;
        while (line[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (!strncmp(&line[i],var_name,length_var_name))
            {
                j = i + length_var_name;
                while (line[j] != '\0')
                {
                    if ( line[j] >= '0' && line[j] <= '9')
                    {
                        *var = (T) atof(&line[j]);
                        inClientFile->seekg( 0, ios_base::beg ); //back to the beginning of the file
                        return 0;
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}

cerr << var_name << " - cannot be found" << endl;
throw "error reading input data from: ";

return 1; //the specified variable was not found in the file
}
```

For example:

the parameters in the txt are as follows:,the type of them are long,

```
 nx=100;
 ny=100;
 nz=100;
 ipro=1;
 jpro=1;
 kpro=1;
```

but after reading the txt in my program I get these,

```
 nx=100;
 ny=100;
 nz=15;
 ipro=1;
 jpro=1;
 kpro=100;
```

I have tested the program under Windows, there it works!

Comment: why do you go back to the beginning of the file after each param?

Comment: why do you use `atof` if the type of parameters are long ?

Comment: ah I see you call that function for each parameter. seems like an awfully complicated way of reading the parameters, though. why not simply scan the file **once** line by line and store param name and value in a fitting structure, e.g. a `map<string, long>`?

Comment: I think the function has no error,because I had tested it in Windows,it works well.but in Linux,it has something wrong just like I say. I have many parameters in the txt file,they may be long,int,char and so on.@nyarlathotep @Michael

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_line

Comment: @kenan, `istream::getline` returns `istream&`, you can't use that in a `while` condition.

Comment: @Michael Yes you can, `istream` overloads the `operator void*()` in order to check a failure in a boolean expression.

Comment: "it works on Windows" != "is free of bugs" - I would suggest stepping through your function with a debugger and checking to make sure it's doing what you think it is...

Comment: @kenan I can't reproduce the bug neither on *Windows* with *MinGW 4.6* nor on *Linux* with *GCC 4.7*. What compiler and system are you using ?

Comment: Thanks for your help,and I have solved the problem. There is something wrong in the process of compilaton. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me, you must have an error somewhere else or an undefined behavior I didn't spot.

May I suggest a more C++ way to do exactly the same thing :

```
template <class T>
T ReadFileVar(ifstream& inClientFile, string var_name)
{
    string line;
    while (getline(inClientFile, line))
    {
        if (line[0] != '/' && line[1] != '/')
        {
            size_t pos = line.find(var_name);
            if( pos != string::npos) {
                pos = line.find('=', pos + 1);
                if(pos == string::npos) {
                    throw std::exception();
                }
                istringstream iss(line.substr(pos + 1));
                T result;
                iss >> result;
                inClientFile.seekg( 0, ios_base::beg );
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    throw std::exception();
}
```

You could also parse the whole file and store the result in a `map` instead of searching the whole file for each variable :

```
map<string, string> ParseFile(ifstream& inClientFile) {
    map<string, string> result;
    string line;
    while (getline(inClientFile, line))
    {
        if (line[0] != '/' && line[1] != '/')
        {
            size_t pos = line.find('=');
            if(pos == string::npos) {
                throw std::exception();
            }
            string var_name = line.substr(0, pos);
            string var_value = line.substr(pos + 1);
            result[var_name] = var_value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

template <class T>
T ReadVar(map<string, string> data, string var_name)
{
    map<string, string>::iterator it = data.find(var_name);
    if(it == data.end()) {
        throw exception();
    }
    string value = it->second;
    istringstream iss(value);
    T result;
    iss >> result;
    return result;
}
```